# Simple CRM wordpress plugins

Tags: wordpress

Am new to WordPress, and i want to create a system using this CMS, nothing complicated i guess, but i have spent to much time looking for plugins that can help me, and there is a lot that its confusing me. 
well, the idea is to give a number of users the ability to fill a form, That will be displayed, edited,and then saved by an other member (basically an other team). also the second team can get any form by (Name, Date/time of creation, or user (who created the form)...). i Hope that someone can point me to some plugins that can help, hope i was clear. Thanks a lot

Comment: check this plugin http://www.gravityforms.com/

Comment: First i Appreciate the answer, this plugin is really cool, but i don't know if it will handle the view of those forms too, if a member tries to edit the form will i need an other plugin or GravityForm will? its the most important thing for me, how to view the collected forms and edited them

Comment: There are CRM WordPress plugins that work with form builders to capture information and put it in a database where you can make further changes, edits etc. to them.  One that might work for your case is [WP Contacts](https://codecanyon.net/item/wp-contacts-contact-management-plugin/11871172), this one in particular integrates with Gravity forms, Contact Form 7 and Ninja forms.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Have you tested this plugin -  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wsdesk/